# Is the sefer Knesses Hagedolah on the Tur in print?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, tur

There is a sefer that I see quoted on the Tur Yoreh Deah called Knesses Hagedolah (they are hagahos). I have looked for this book and could not find it. Is it printed as a separate book? Is it available?

Comment: The entire thing is available at HebrewBooks.org. See the bottom of the [Wikipedia article](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%99) for links.

Answer (score 2):

The old print of the sefer is available [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx?title=%u05DB%u05E0%u05E1%u05EA%20%u05D4%u05D2%u05D3%u05D5%u05DC%u05D4&auth=%u05D1%u05E0%u05D1%u05E0%u05E9%u05EA%u05D9&ocr=&sort=0) on HebrewBooks. A newer print of it was published in the 1980's by Machon HaKtav, I'm not sure if you can buy printed copies anymore (my yeshiva has it in their library), but this new print (as well as the old one) is available on [Otzar HaChochma](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/otzar.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can still buy the machon haktav one, I saw them selling it at one of there sales contact them at Jerusalem it is absolutely huge though, like 23 volumes, they sell them individually